# Reusing a multiple-entry Schengen visa obtained for business for a backpacking trip

Tags: visas, schengen, europe, backpacking

I have this multiple-entry Schengen visa. I got my visa because of a recent business trip to Poland (Polish embassy issued my visa, with R/PL remark). After my business trip, I'm planning to go back to Europe for backpacking, but I don't have any plans to visit Poland.

Now I'm wondering if I can use my visa (issued by the Polish embassy) for my Europe backpacking trip? I mean, if they restrict me to visit Poland because their embassy is the one who issued my visa?

By the way, my entry point is Vienna, then Prague, Berlin, Amsterdam, Belgium, and my exit point is Paris going back to Philippines.

Comment: @domiao Your question may have an answer here https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/81075/schengen-visa-with-r-lv-under-remarks

Answer (score 4):

As Layth pointed out, the Schengen authorities gave a multiple entry visa for *your and their* convenience, they found you trustworthy enough that they don't want to be bothered by you for every single entry. Your visa is valid for all Schengen states.

Think through your proposed trip **as if** you were preparing a new visa application.

- Premise of the trip.
- Start and end date, where and how you will leave the Schengen area again.
- Where you will stay and how you will travel between cities. You might not have firm plans in this regard, but gather information like "the train from Berlin to Amsterdam leaves weekdays every two hours, €126,40 or slightly less if I book early."
- What you are going to spend, if you can reasonably afford it, and how you will bring the money. (A mix of cash and credit cards? What else?)
- Medical insurance.

When you arrive at Vienna airport, you should be able to explain this information in a coherent way. That would be easier if you had hotel reservations all the way, but enough money on hand can compensate for that.

Answer (score 2):

Since you've been granted a Schengen visa with multiple entries, you're entitled to the Schengen Area Agreement that gives you the absolute freedom to go around the SA countries demonstrating that you follow the intended purpose of your visa and restrictions or staying and/or committing illegal activities there.

[Schengen Agreement Policies](https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/schengen-agreement/)

Comment: Welcome to travel.stackexchange!